# ImageIcon, only half of image is being displayed

Tags: java, swing

I have no idea what is happening here as i've done painting quite a lot here but this is driving me mad. The m_background image is only getting half of it displayed. When I resize it looks like their is some component there so when I bring the bottom of the window up less images shows and when I bring it down it shows more.

This image is only 600x600 but only around 250 pixels are showing.
Ive tried to remove everything on the pane and that isn't doing anything.

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LudoGameController extends JPanel {

    private JFrame m_ludoFrame;
    private int m_humanValue;
    private int m_computerValue;
    private JPanel m_boardPanel;
    private ImageIcon m_background = new ImageIcon("images/background.png");

    public LudoGameController(JFrame m_ludoFrame, int m_humanValue, int m_computerValue) throws IOException {
        this.m_ludoFrame = m_ludoFrame;
        this.m_humanValue = m_humanValue;
        this.m_computerValue = m_computerValue;
        m_ludoFrame.add(this);
        m_ludoFrame.setSize(1000, 700);
        m_ludoFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(m_background.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're asking "why is my code not working", but we're stuck since we can't run and test your code. Best if you could create and post a [mcve] or better [sscce](http://sscce.org), one that uses an image available for all online, and that shows your error directly for us.

Comment: As a side recommendation, I'd change `g.drawImage(m_background.getImage(), 0, 0, null);` to `g.drawImage(m_background.getImage(), 0, 0, this);`

Comment: I'd also avoid using ImageIcons when I really only want to use an Image.

Comment: your convoluted design of having a panel that will call a frame that will be added to itself and making it its own gives me trouble - and calling yourself an experienced panel director doesnt help either

Comment: @gpasch is it your goal just point out all my flaws on here?

Comment: @PigeonMilkStories Welcome to a public forum ;) Pointing out your "flaws" is one way to help you solve your problem

Comment: `g.drawImage(m_background.getImage(), 0, 0, null);` should be `g.drawImage(m_background.getImage(), 0, 0, this);` and I also agree with the other comments, use `ImageIO.read` instead of `ImageIcon`

Comment: Your `LudoGameController` should also be overriding the `getPreferredSize` method a should return a suitable size for the component

Comment: @MadProgrammer I understand that premise but that gpasch has just ripped me to shreds on almost every ive ever made lol

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with only image, It is better not to use `ImageIcon`. Instead use `ImageIO` class like below to load the image from the file:

First declare a class variable `background` as type `Image` and initialise it to `null`.

Then in your constructor add the following code to get the image from file

```
File file = new File("images/background.png");
try {
    background = ImageIO.read(file).getScaledInstance(1000, 700, Image.SCALE_FAST);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

Now in your `paintComponent` method replace

```
g.drawImage(m_background.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
```

with

```
g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Could attempt to use a JLabel with icon and see if that behaves differently. Below is a snippet of code I've used successfully many times in scenarios similar to yours.

```
//bringing in the image
File file = new File("images/background.png");
try {
    BufferedImage logo = ImageIO.read(file);
    JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(logo));
    logoPanel.add(logoLabel);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: but the image has to be added to the background of the `JPanel`. You are suggesting it to be added to a panel